# How to Use IGraphicsContainer.BringForward?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, c#

I'm making an add-in for ArcMap using ArcObjects.

I'm trying to bring an `IElement` that I've added to the `ArcMap.Editor.Map.ActiveGraphicsLayer` layer up one level in Z-Order. How do I add my `IElement` to a `IEnumElement` so that I can cast the `ActiveGraphicsLayer` to an `IGraphicsContainer` and invoke `IGraphicsContainer.BringForward(IEnumElement Elements)`?

There is no example documentation for situations other than using the existing user selection.

**Update:** I've tried doing the VB example in C# like so. The element still doesn't come to the top.

```
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto;

namespace XivicToolbar.ArcMapRelated
{
    internal class MapGraphics
    {
        private static IGraphicsContainer Graphics => (IGraphicsContainer)ArcMap.Editor.Map.ActiveGraphicsLayer;

        public void Indicate(IElement element, int zIndex)
        {
            //Add the element 
            Graphics.Reset();
            Graphics.AddElement(element, zIndex);

            //Do z indexing
            for (; zIndex > 0; zIndex--)
            {
                var graphicsSelection = (IGraphicsContainerSelect)Graphics;
                graphicsSelection.UnselectAllElements();
                graphicsSelection.SelectElement(element);
                Graphics.BringForward(graphicsSelection.SelectedElements);
                graphicsSelection.UnselectElement(element);
            }

            //Update the UI
            Refresh();
        }

        private static void Refresh() => ArcMap.Document.ActiveView.PartialRefresh(esriViewDrawPhase.esriViewGraphics, null, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a VBA sample on GeoNet https://geonet.esri.com/thread/46865 using the document as an IGraphicsContainer but it should work in your case as ICompositeGraphicsLayer implements IGraphicsContainer but I think there's an error in it, gc.BringForward g.SelectedElements should be gc.BringForward g**cs**.SelectedElements; the workflow seems to be to iterate through the elements, select the one(s) you want then bring them all forward as IGraphicsContainerSelect.SelectedElements then I would say call IGraphicsContainerSelect.UnselectAllElements to clean up.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a work-around by calling the "bring forward" and "send backward" buttons in place of calling `Graphics.BringForward(graphicsSelection.SelectedElements)`. It's pretty nasty but it gets the job done.

```
 public static void InvokeButton(string id)
 {
     var commandButton = ArcMap.Application.Document.CommandBars.Find(new UID { Value = id });
     commandButton.Execute();
 }
```

The IDs are:

Send Backward - `"{92D490B5-DF9D-11D1-8779-0000F8751720}"`

Bring Forward - `"{92D490B4-DF9D-11D1-8779-0000F8751720}"`